# Why DefaultModelBinder in MVC3 does not Bind?

Tags: c#, data-binding, asp.net-mvc-3

I do not understand why the **DefaultModelBinder** in MVC3 does not map the Form Post Data to my action method. I have the following **ViewModels**:

```
public class DisplayExcelTableViewModel
{
   public string UploadedFileName { get; set; }
   public List<string> TableHeaders { get; set; }
   public List<TableRowViewModel> TableRows { get; set; }
}

public class TableRowViewModel
{
   public List<string> TableColumns { get; set; }
}
```

They are displayed in a **(partial) View** using **DisplayTemplates**:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitExcel", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
<fieldset>

<table>
<tr>
<th>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TableHeaders)</th>//<input id="TableHeaders_0_" name="TableHeaders[0]" type="text" value="Opportunity Id" />
</tr>

<tr>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TableRows)</td>//<input id="TableRows_0__TableColumns_0_" name="TableRows[0].TableColumns[0]" type="text" value="1-H7PKD9" />
</tr>

</table>           


<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</fieldset> 
}
```

And the action method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult SubmitExcel(DisplayExcelTableViewModel excelTable)
```

To try whether it worked just with one **TableRows** I tried:

```
public ActionResult SubmitExcel([Bind(Prefix = "TableRows")] TableRowViewModel TableRows)
```

to test I also tried to put `List<TableRows>` and take out the **Bind attribute**. It does not work.
I got a runtime exception:

**"System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object."**

May you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks Francesco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that my ViewModels **DID NOT** have a **parameterless constructor**, which is what the **Default Model Binder** looks for(uses .NET’s Activator.CreateInstance() method, which relies on those types having public parameterless constructors).The solutions in this case are two:

1) Add a parameterless constructor to the ViewModel and the other custom classes wrapped inside it.

2) Create a custom model binder that covers also the case of your ViewModel

Thanks

Source: Pro ASP.NET MVC2 Framework (2nd Edition)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked (for example with Firebug) whether are form values being posted to the server? I'm asking because `Html.DisplayFor` usually renders display elements, whereas for posting values you usually have to use `Html.EditorFor`.

Comment: thenaks for the answer. I use Fiddler 2 and the data are correctly posted to the server